# How to redirect the output to file and print required words line by line in python

Tags: android, python

Am beginner in python I have just extracted permissions from an file using python through this code

```
def remove_prefix(text, prefix):
    if text.startswith(prefix):
        return text[len(prefix):]
    return text

file = open('op3.txt', 'w')
from xml.dom.minidom import parseString

data = ''
with open('C:/Users/kireet/Desktop/AndroidManifest.xml','r') as f:
    data = f.read()
    dom = parseString(data)
    nodes = dom.getElementsByTagName('uses-permission')
    # Iterate over all the uses-permission nodes
    for node in nodes:
        perm=node.getAttribute('android:name')
        perm1=remove_prefix(perm,'android.permission.')
        print(perm1)
        file.write(perm1)
```

I have got output as:

> INTERNET
>
> ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
>
> ACCESS_WIFI_STATE
>
> RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED
>
> READ_PHONE_STATE
>
> WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
>
> WAKE_LOCK
>
> com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT
>
> GET_TASKS
>
> EXPAND_STATUS_BAR
>
> SET_WALLPAPER
>
> CAMERA
>
> MANAGE_DOCUMENTS
>
> READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
>
> ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
>
> ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
>
> CHANGE_WIFI_STATE
>
> READ_LOGS
>
> VIBRATE
>
> RECORD_AUDIO
>
> com.google.android.gms.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION
>
> READ_CALENDAR
>
> WRITE_CALENDAR
>
> GET_ACCOUNTS
>
> USE_CREDENTIALS

but the same output when redirected to file shows the output in a single  line without any spaces as:

> INTERNETACCESS_NETWORK_STATEACCESS_WIFI_STATERECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETEDREAD_PHONE_STATEWRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGEWAKE_LOCKcom.android.launcher.

can any one help how to get the output of required permissions line by  line in a redirected file?

Comment: Try `file.write('\n')` under `file.write(perm1)` to write a newline character.

Comment: Also, if that's your complete code, you're not closing the file at the end.

Comment: This question was open in an old tab. Please consider marking danidee's answer correct; it's similar to my comment but I chose not to post as an answer. Clicking the tick next to his answer will close this issue (tell others that it's solved) and reward someone for spending their time reading, understanding and answering your question. You will also get reputation for it.

Answer (score 0):

add a new line character when writing the strings

`file.write(perm1 + '\n')`